# react-native-progress-webview Unable to resolve module

Tags: react-native, webview

I found this project interesting at the NPM,
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-progress-webview

however I followed the instruction, it shows the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `react-native-progess-webview` from `mycomponent.js`: Module `react-native-progess-webview` does not exist in the Haste module map
```

I already installed 'react-native-webview' and it works fine, however `react-native-progess-webview` seems not able to be imported.

I am just simply importing the library like this:

```
import ProgressWebView from "react-native-progess-webview";
```

How to solve?

Answer (score 3):

I found that it is a typo in the tutorial, in the tutorial it is:

```
import ProgressWebView from "react-native-progess-webview";
```

but the correct one is:

```
import ProgressWebView from "react-native-progress-webview";
```

There is an "r" in the "progress".

Answer (score 0):

npm i react-native-webview worked for me